# Accessing audio media streams in SIP call in nodejs using sip.js

Tags: node.js, webrtc, sip.js

I'm using the latest version of sip.js (0.21.2) in a nodejs app.  I have an external device that sends and accepts packets of G.711 ulaw encoded audio using RTSP.  I am able to instantiate my SIP client, and able to  call that SIP client and accept the call.  However, I'm floundering in what to do next in order to handle the RTP packets to and from the caller.  My intent is to act as a proxy between the caller and the external device shunting audio packet between the two.

I'm really struggling to figure out what to do next.  It feels like creating a custom MediadHandlerFactory is the way to go,  but beyond that I really don't have any good ideas about what to do there.

Would anyone out there be able to offer any sort of help or information as to how I should proceed?

Thanks in advance